# Change from address of user registration email

Tags: 7, users, emails

How can I update the from address of the email sent when a user successfully registers to the website. Currently the from address is same as the site administrator email id. Instead I would like to set it some custom email id like do-not-reply@example.com.

I looked at the [Mail editor](https://drupal.org/project/mail_edit) module and from the documentation I understand that it can be used only for updating the subject and body of the email and not the from address.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

There is one e-mail address that is used as From-address for *all* mails sent automatically by the system.  By default, this is set to the *same* as the site administrator email.  To change it, do the following:

1. Navigate to *Administration » Configuration » System » Site Information*.
2. Locate the field "E-mail address". Change it to whatever you want it to be.
3. Press *Save configuration*.

Note that will also be used as the From-adress for password resets and other generated mail.

If you require fine-tuning beyond this (to distinguish between different types of auto-generated email messages), you need to write a custom module. In that case, you may use [`hook_mail_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to alter the From:-address, based upon some criteria (e.g. the subject field.

For avoidance of misunderstanding: The three steps listed above will *not* change the site administrator email id.  To inspect and change the site administrator email id, click on the  "My account" link while logged in as site admin, and then press the *Edit* tab to see it. The  site administrator email id is by *default* the same email id as the From-address used for email sent by the site itself - but they do not need to be the same.

Comment: My question is definitely not on how to edit the site administrator email id. I will no way want to update it to do-not-reply.XXX. I only want to update the from address in the email. Custom module sounds fine but is there a hook available for it or if you can give more details on how it can be done then it would be helpful.

Comment: @Bhuvana, I do *not* propose that you change  the site administrator email id.  The site administrator email id will remain the same if you go through the three steps listed in my answer to change the From-address of auto-generated email (such as the user registration email).

Comment: @Bhuvana, as per Free Radical, The administrator email is the one set on your _user account_, the Site Information email is the _site_ email, and designed specifically for this.